# C++ Macro: How to capture everything before recognizable string literal

Tags: c++, macros

I need to transform `<unknown_variable_name_before_dot>.NestedObject.` to `static_cast<NestedClass>(<unknown_variable_name_before_dot>.NestedObject).`.

For example:

```
Foo foo;
Foo bar;

// I don't know the variable name, but I do know ".NestedObject." will be present
foo.NestedObject.Func();
bar.NestedObject.Func();

// I need to force the call into the following syntax
static_cast<NestedClass>(foo.NestedObject).Func();
static_cast<NestedClass>(bar.NestedObject).Func();
```

Is this possible to do with C macros?

I expect the result to be something similar to...

`static_cast<NestedClass>(##<unknown_variable_name_before_dot>.NestedObject).`

..., but I don't know how to capture the unknown/variable portion of the string before the part of the string I do recognize.

If `operator .` were available, then I would have something similar to...

```
NestedClass & operator . (void) {
    return *this;
}
```

#### Goal

The goal is to allow syntax like `foo.NestedObject.Func();`, but enforce the `static_cast<NestedClass>` without the user knowing/caring.

Comment: Can you show us your macro?

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. I know that preprocessor text replacement is possible with macros, but I do not know how to leverage them to achieve my goal. How do I improve my question?

Comment: @Galik I don't know how to make the macro, that is what I need help with. I only know the problem I need to solve, which I have shared above. Does the code sample clarify the intent of question?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to do something like

```
FUNKY(foo);
FUNKY(bar);
```

all you need is

```
#define FUNKY(x) static_cast<NestedClass>(x.NestedObject).Func()
```

Since you are not concatenating to a name, you do not need to use ##

Comment: But this wont evaluate `x`. And whatever the `x` param will be, it will stay `x.NestedObject`.

Comment: I've added a goal that I didn't make clear before, the goal is to allow the unmodified syntax to enforce a typing. I'm doing this because I cannot use `operator .` (not available). Your solution would require `FUNKY(foo).NestedObject.Func()`, correct?

Comment: Macros will substitute the parameter - just run it with the preprocessor and see what it generates.  Just call as specified at the beginning of the answer.  I can't understand what you mean by not being able to use the . operator.  Which . operator can you not use - the one before NestedObject or the one before Func.  Why can't you use it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define DO_VAR(x) _##x.pop_back();    // There has to be something before '##x', you can replace '_' with whatever you want.

int main()
{
    std::string _test = "test";

    DO_VAR(test)

    std::cout << _test << std::endl; // Prints: tes

    return 0;
}
```

This piece of code works and prints out `tes` which means it really poped back last character.

So you could create `foo.NestedObject.Func();`

But if you want to add cast `static_cast<NestedClass>` before this, compiler throws an error:

> error: ‘NestedClass’ does not name a type  #define DO_VAR(x)
>   static_cast _##x.pop_back();

So i dont think its possible to create it with cast.
The C preprocessor is very limited in what it can do. You could look into `m4` for a stronger preprocessor, but you're likely headed down the wrong road.

So in my opinion maximum you can create is

```
foo.NestedObject.Func();
```

Hope it helped you a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't want to have observable `MACRO_FUNC` syntax in the code. I want it to find the literal string I'm looking for (i.e. `.NestedObject.`, and collect all code before it.

Comment: Its not possible. You cant create macro which will modify your code like that. Only if you pass it to macro like i did. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you Filip that is the response I needed.